# PDF contains encoded content

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

Through a web service I get a PDF response. When I hit the endpoint through my browser the file is downloaded and saved as I would expect.

**The problem:** when I open the downloaded PDF the content appears to be encoded. If I paste the PDF content into something like MS Word or even Chrome, it becomes readable english.

[image]

I have opened the PDF using my code editor to inspect the metadata, but I don't know what exactly I'm looking for.

How can I get the content to display as readable english when the PDF is opened?

Any help would be much, much appreciated!

Here is a link to the PDF in question: [testPDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-zoQLZM1WK2ek5OcEdnS3NCb28/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: What exactly is the question? And how can we inspect the pdf to help?

Comment: @mkl - I updated the post with a more specific question and link to the PDF file.

Comment: The PDF file is utterly broken. PDF is a binary format but by the looks of it some software processed it like text (which by itself already is likely to damage binary files) and then even changed the assumed encoding upon saving. This damaged the embedded font resulting in a replacement font with different glyph codes being used for display. Either the web service itself does the damage or your way of download. As you call the provider a "web service", it probably does not provide the information required for a browser to correctly download the file, merely for dedicated web clients.

Comment: Thus... *"How can I get the content to display as readable english when the PDF is opened?"* - try implementing a web client downloading the PDF as a binary file. Check this file. If that also creates a broken PDF, tell the web service provider and ask him to repair the service.